# Should "corrective action" votes disappear when they expire?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

By "corrective action", I mean close/delete/undelete or any other type of vote that may change a post's good-standing status.

Refer to [this thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5475/197), but I'm sure there's more like it.

The thread received a single close vote on the day it was created, January 5th.  However, today on January 9th, I still see that there is one close vote on the thread.  Aren't these supposed to expire after 2 days?

Of course, one thought may be that another close vote has been submitted in the past two days while the first one expired.  I checked this with the moderator tools though - the thread referenced above does not show as having had a close vote posted in the past two days.

So, are these votes not actually expiring or do they just not disappear when they do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they expire after 4 days.

`Questions.CloseVotesAgeThreshold    4`

Comment: ...and it seems it has.  Why do I remember two days?  Was this changed recently-ish?

Comment: @Iszi Spam/offensive flags age in 2 days. That's probably what you were thinking of.